# Wrong way to use MVT to prove inequality

Tags: inequality

I am asked to show that $|\sin x - \sin y| \leq |x-y|$ using the mean value theorem. What I have done seems 'fishy'. I defined $h(x) = |x-y|-|\sin x - \sin y| $. Then $h'(x) = 1 - |\cos x| \geq 0$ Thus h is increasing and $h(x) \geq 0$. Therefore $|\sin x - \sin y| \leq.  |x-y|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTV says that if $x\ne y$, then
$$\frac{\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}=\sin'(\xi)$$
for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$. This means that
$$|\sin x-\sin y|=|x-y||\sin'\xi|=|x-y||\cos\xi|\le|x-y|$$
because $|\cos \xi|\le1$.

If $x=y$, then the inequality is true trivially.

Comment: Thank you all, I guess it is a good idea to REALLY understand the meaning of the MVT. I rushed to fast into doing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fact that $| \cos \alpha | \leq 1 $ for all $\alpha $. Notice by MVT, we can find $c$ such that

$$ |\sin x - \sin y | = | \cos c | | x - y | \leq |x - y | $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sin x ,$ we have $$|f(x) -f(y)|=|f'(c)||x-y|\leq |x-y|.$$